# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to connect my grails project to Oracle databse(**Oracle 12c**) in windows(8) system. However, whenever I run my application I get following exception :

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040: 
No matching authentication protocol)

Caused by: 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: 
No matching authentication protocol
```

According to internet suggestion I also tried editing my  **`*.ora`** file but it is not working.

I added following snippet in **`sqlnet.ora`** file :

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=10
```

Here i tried assigning (10,11,12) but neither of them is working.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

I deleted the ***ojdbc14.jar*** file and used ***ojdbc6.jar*** instead and it worked for me

Comment: experience same issue while trying to connect Oracle 12c from pentaho kettle. 
removed ojdbc14.jar and its perfectly working!

Comment: Same error when Connecting Cognos 10.2.1 fp7 to Oracle 12c content store database.  Removed ojdbc14.jar from '[10 bi install folder]\webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib' and added ojdbc6.jar, works great.

Comment: In my case i need swap ojdbc14.jar for ojdbc7.jar in my tomcat lib on: `Apache\tomcat-7.0.27\lib'

Comment: At least a brief explanation **why** this should work would be quite handy.

Comment: For me, changing to ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc7.jar still failed because I had been constantly setting: `oracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability"="o3"` which you no longer have to do against oracle 12c. Hope it can help someone else

Comment: Worked for me as well.  Wish eclipse made errors and exceptions clearer.  Oh well.

Comment: @JamesTobin Thanks a ton, that fixed the issue for me. It might be worth posting that as a separate answer so it's easier to find.

Comment: That works perfect after deleting ojdbc14.jar and using the ojdbc6.jar

Comment: make sure it is in lib folder not ext folder.

Comment: I have replaced OJDBC14.jar by OJDBC6.jar and now the program build on ORACLE 10 server work on Developement PC with Oracle 12C without building original Java program.

Comment: @YuriyKravets The number **14** in **ojdbc14.jar** and number **6** in **ojdbc6.jar** refers to the JDK version they were written for.

If you open the **ojdbc14.jar's** manifest file, it says: 
_Specification-Title:    "Oracle JDBC driver classes for use with JDK1.4"_

Similarly, ojdbc6.jar supports JDK1.6 implementation.

Comment: @Maverick well... that's one of the most unfortunate versioning convention I've seen to far.

Comment: @YuriyKravets you should go to your oracle_home directory ... you will find a directory named "jdbc" ... in this folder you will find the proper jar files for jdbc use... this is why you should change the version of jar file in question answer... hope this help someone

Comment: I also faced same issue. but I resolved based on jdk and its version. So it depends on which Jdk version is used. if you are using Jdk 1.6 then ojdbc6.jar  is required to be used.  if you are using a higher version of Jdk then you can latest version of ojdbcX. jar

Comment: Also if you are working on intellij, please restart after making changes and also check "external libraries" on the left shows the right oracle driver

Comment: In my case I was connecting to Oracle 19c. oracle8.jar worked for me.

Comment: @NilucshanSiva That's wrong. I'm using oracle8.jar and Oracle 19c and still get this error.

Answer (score 60):

Here is some text I found at [experts-exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_28387999.html):

> Bug 14575666
>
> In 12.1, the default value for the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION
>   parameter has been updated to 11. This means that database clients
>   using pre-11g JDBC thin drivers cannot authenticate to 12.1 database
>   servers unless theSQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter is set to the
>   old default of 8.
>
> This will cause a 10.2.0.5 Oracle RAC database creation using DBCA to
>   fail with the ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol error in
>   12.1 Oracle ASM and Oracle Grid Infrastructure environments.
>
> Workaround:  Set SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in the
>   oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file.

Comment: Just for reference: This worked for me not deleting the ojdbc14.jar file and using ojdbc6.jar

Comment: yes, in my case this solved the issue, but another occured : invalid username/password. btw i was trying to connect from oracle jdeveloper 10 to oracle database 12c. so this gave be the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie#14477188

finally had to: 1) change SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION to 8 2) SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES to (NONE)
3) ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE
4) ALTER USER XX IDENTIFIED BY PW (to resave the password now that we changed case-sensitivity)

Comment: Late to the party, but I've also confirmed this fix. I _had_ to set my version = 8 even though I was running JDBC 11 -- nothing newer than 8 worked.

Comment: I am using a remote database server, i do not have access to machine, I can just connect to database using SQL Developer (Without error), but my application (deployed on Tomcat ) throws this error.  I have changed the settings at my local machine, it is not working. Do i have to modify the settings on server machine?

Comment: I don't have access to `oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora` nor do you say where this file is

Answer (score 13):

This except for adding the following to sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

If you get "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" error, then you need to re-create your password.

Answer (score 9):

I resolved this issue by using ojdbc8.jar. 
Oracle 12c is compatible with ojdbc8.jar

Answer (score 6):

I was using eclipse and after trying all the other answers it didn't work for me. 
In the end, what worked for me was moving the `ojdb7.jar` to top in the Build Path. This occurs when multiple jars have conflicting same classes.

> 1. Select project in `Project Explorer`
> 2. Right click on `Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path`
> 3. Go to `Order and Export` tab and select `ojdbc.jar`
> 4. Click button `TOP` to move it to top

Answer (score 4):

Very old question but providing some additional information which may help someone else. I also encountered same error and I was using ojdbc14.jar with 12.1.0.2 Oracle Database. On Oracle official web page this information is listed that which version supports which database drivers. [Here is the link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) and it appears that with Oracle 12c and Java 7 or 8 the correct version is ojdbc7.jar.

In the ojdbc6.jar is for 11.2.0.4.

Answer (score 3):

Except for adding the following to **sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

I also added the following to both the Client and Server, which resolved my issue

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

Also see post
[ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398101/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol/43362249#43362249)

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

is the perfect solution
sql.ora directory 
..\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

Answer (score 0):

My Initial error is : ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception

My DB version is 12.2 (Solaris) and client version is 11.2 ( windows). I have added below in both server and client sqlnet.ora

SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8

while connecting, I have got invalid username and password hence I have recreated the password ( same password ) in database which is resolved my issue.

Comment: I don't see that error only ORA-28040 downvote –

Answer (score 0):

While for most cases replacing ojdbc driver jar will be the solution, my case was different.

If you are certain you are using correct ojdbc driver. Double check if you are actually connecting to the database you are thinking you are. In my case jdbc configuration (in Tomcat/conf) was pointing to different database that had different Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

Using ojdbc8.jar helped me with birt connection issue:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

I downloaded it from https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/otn_software/jdbc/1918/ojdbc8.jar

Answer (score -1):

just install ojdbc-full, That contains the 12.1.0.1 release.