# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception when using groovy.sql package with oracle12c

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, groovy, oracle12c

I am trying to connect to *oracle12c* database using *groovy.sql.Sql*

```
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:thin:@'+hostName:port/serviceName, dbUser, dbPassword, 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
```

and it returns

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

I guess, this is because of the **dialect** mismatch.

It works fine with *oracle11g*, but not with *12c*. If it is a problem with *dialect*, how can we externally specify *dialect* to *groovy.sql.Sql*. If not, what could be the problem/solution?

I'm using *ojdbc14* driver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ojdbc14` is a relatively old driver and that could be the problem.  I would recommend trying `ojdbc6` and see if that fixes your problem.

Note that this appeared to fix a similar problem based on information in the comments in this SO question [ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception).

Comment: Yes, `ojdbc6` has fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the dialect that is normally configured in `DataSource.groovy`? If so, this is irrelevant when creating an `Sql` instance, because the dialect is only used by Hibernate/GORM.

Comment: No, actually I am trying to dynamically connect to some other databases from my application.