# Connecting ColdFusion 8 to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, jdbc, coldfusion, database-connection

I am trying to connect from a basic install of ColdFusion 8 to an Oracle 12c database. It currently connects with Oracle 11g without a problem.

I am getting the following error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: test
>    java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
>  
>    The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Comment: Strictly a guess, but it might be a driver issue.

Comment: Yep, check these other answers, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100117/1636917 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31141392/1636917

Comment: Upgrading drivers should work, but I have to put on my Fear-Monger hat again: I think the biggest issue is that you are running ColdFusion 8. That version is extremely out of date and incredibly vulnerable to all sorts of outside exploitation. You're updating Oracle (which isn't inexpensive itself), so you shouldn't neglect ColdFusion. Or the elderly OS that is likely running to be compatible with CF8. I understand that upgrading CF may be outside your responsibility, but CF8 invites tons of headaches (for both you and your org) that are easily handled with a modern version of CF or Lucee.

Comment: Upgrading CF8 and Oracle are both out of my hands. I can not change the system, or the underlying architecture. Want to laugh? The server is Windows 2008, service pack 1. And it was setup in 2016. YES, the helpful individual who built the system used out of date tech to start with.

We are running CF8 with Oracle 11g, I need to connect to another database within the system that is 12c.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 12c is not supported by the drivers that ColdFusion 8 Enterprise comes with.  You could try using different drivers but might run into other problems even if they do manage to connect.

Comment: Recent JDBC drivers are available from Oracle: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html They require JAVA 8 or above. No idea if this works with CF 8.

Comment: If it requires Java8, it won't work with CF8. CF8 is *really* old and only supports Java 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is older versions of drivers will not able to connect 12c server. In Oracle 12.1, the default value for the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` parameter is set to 11. This means that database clients using pre-11g drivers cannot authenticate to 12.1 database servers unless the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` parameter is set to the old default of 8 in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora`

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

Note that `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` has been deprecated in 12c.

Check below link for more info

https://www.oracleracexpert.com/2019/01/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication.html