# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am trying to connect oracle12C but not able to connect .

i have tried with previous answer : 
[ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol : Oracle 12c Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141392/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-oracle-12c-upgrade)?

using ojdbc6.jar . But it is not worked

Next i have added following snippet in sqlnet.ora file

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=10
```

Here i tried assigning (10,11,12) but neither of them is working.

Comment: can you try version 8

Comment: yes tried even that . under sqlnet.ora

Comment: after update to sqlnet.ora you need to reload the listener. `lsnrctl reload` or restart the server (if you can)

Comment: Also try with the minimum version supported which is 8. You need to do this both on client and server

Answer (score 1):

After Lot of debug ,

Oracle 12c comes all its older version . If you have installed 11g client first upgrade to 12c . Then all set up need to done . Net manager wont throw ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol Oracle error and will pass successfully .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try delete the **ojdbc14.jar** file and use **ojdbc6.jar** instead

Comment: Yes i have tried even that under Lib folder but didn't worked for me