# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am facing this issue even after following the below settings.

1. Replacing `ojdbc14.jar` with `ojdbc6.jar`[also tried `ojdbc5.jar`]
2. Added "`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8`" to sqlnet.ora
   file[under network/admin folder].

This is happening after upgrading the DB from 11g to 12c.

Answer (score 3):

JDBC drivers have both a Java version and an Oracle version.  The versions are usually correlated, but it's possible for an ojdbc14.jar to support a later version of Oracle than a ojdbc6.jar.  Make sure you are using the latest version of ojdbc6.jar.

Run this command to see which version of Oracle the driver was built for:

```
>java -jar ojdbc6.jar -getversion
Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Thu_Jun_28_00:38:25_PDT_2012
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Mon Dec 21 12:38:41 CST 2015
```

For SQLNET.ORA changes, to be safe you should restart both the listener and the database.  This sounds extreme, but there are some parameters that [require restarting the database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54606/change-oracle-banner-without-restarting-database).

Also make sure that you are modifying all relevant SQLNET.ORA files.  If the database's Oracle home is different than the listener's Oracle home you should modify both.

Answer (score 3):

```
ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

I faced a similar issue when trying to connect a

> 32-bit Oracle **11g Client** to a 64-bit Oracle **12c Server**

I then proceeded to add the following to **sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

I then experienced the following error

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password: logon denied
```

Adding the following to the Client **sqlnet.ora** as well as the Server, I was able to connect an old version of Toad and PL/SQL to the new 12c Server.

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all the difference between ojdbc driver's versions depends on the version of the JDK you use drivers with.
So `ojbdc14` is suitable for JDK version 1.4, `ojdbc5` for JDK 1.5, and so on.

I'm currently using `ojdbc7.jar` with a 12c database version since my environment uses a JDK 1.7, so upgrade this first.

Having said that, in the [Parameters for the sqlnet.ora File](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2010) for Oracle 12c release page you can read:

> **Purpose**
>
> To set the minimum authentication protocol allowed for clients, and
>   when a server is acting as a client, such as connecting over a
>   database link, when connecting to Oracle Database instances.
>
> **Usage Notes**
>
> The term VERSION in the parameter name refers to the version of the
>   authentication protocol, not the Oracle Database release.
>
> If the version does not meet or exceed the value defined by this
>   parameter, then authentication fails with an ORA-28040: No matching
>   authentication protocol error.

The default for this property is 11.

Allowed values are 8,10,11,12 and 12a.

The recommended value is 12. Try this out.

Moreover there is a useful and interesting solution [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116316/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol)

Comment: Thanks for you answer Mr.Abarisone. As per said, I have replaced the existing jar with ojdbc7.jar and also updated the sqlnet.ora file to use "SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=12". The sqlnet.ora located at "product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin" was edited. However I am still facing this issue. can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest JDBC thin driver (12.1.0.2) and JDK8. With this configuration your driver will support the latest version of the database password verifier and your issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Oracle 12c or higher versions

for java version jdk7 & jdk8 supported ojdcc7.jar

for java version jdk6 ojdbc6.jar

This worked for us...
Download  [ojdcc7.jar]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).