# AWS RDS - ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, rds

While connecting to Oracle 12c database from Java 8 client code, I got error -"ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception" This was resolved by adding SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in sqlnet.ora file.

Now, when I connect to AWS oracle RDS instance from code running in EC2 instance (RDS and java application running in same subnet), result in same error. Is there an option to add parameter(SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8) in AWS Oracle RDS instance? How can resolve this issue?

Comment: You might want to check the JDBC version as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402352/409172)

Answer (score 1):

The AWS docs list the params you can alter for your needs.

sqlnetora.sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_client
sqlnetora.sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server

I suggest you to play with those.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.Oracle.sqlnet.html