# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 28,040

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, websphere, database-connection, database-administration

I am trying to change the datasource in WebSphere pointing to some other environment. I am able to connect it using toad or sqldeveloper. However when I am trying to test the connection from websphere, it is giving the following error.
"java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 28,040. View JVM logs for further details."

I tried restarting the server but didn't helped. Not sure what is going wrong in this.

Comment: Please show the JDBC url or connection configuration

Comment: Hi adding further to it I am able to connect on WAS 8.5.5.0 with the same string but not on WAS 8.5.0.0. I am trying to connect to exadata, with following url.                                                                      jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (FAILOVER=on) (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = xxx.com ) (PORT = yyyy)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =zzzzz)))
.

Comment: Not sure whether it is WAS compatibility issue or some issue from the database side. But since its working for one WAS and not for other, it seems to be WAS issue.Not sure, y I am getting this error. I tried with the same JDBC driver that was used in WAS 8.5.5.0 i.e ojdbc6.jar

Comment: `ojdbc6.jar` is not a version, it just means it is the driver for Java 6 (JDBC 4.0).

Comment: If you view the JDBC Provider associated with the datasource, what value is listed in the "Class path" field?  Did you restart server after changing the JDBC Provider to point to ojdbc6.jar?

Comment: I  have added this jar and commented the existing one. Then I changed the classpath to ${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar . and it does find it else it gives the driver not found error. But it didn't worked. But finally I found the issue, rather than modifying the existing jdbc driver classpath, we need to create a new configuration because it also updates variables.xml and resources.xml and hence it is able to connect now. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: you may find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any configuration information or server logs, so, assuming the old Oracle connection URL was working prior to you changing it, one common cause of this problem is changing the connection URL to move from an Oracle 11 instance (or earlier) to an Oracle 12 instance without properly updating the classpath of the WebSphere JDBC Provider to use at least the ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: I tried pointing to ojdbc6.jar. Although it used it but still gave the same error. Anything else that needs to be done since the two WAS versions are different, to support Oracle 12c