# Hibernate No matching authentication protocol

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, oracle12c, ojdbc

Initially we were using Oracle 11g database. Now we wanted to upgrade to 12c database, while in testing phase of this migration, we are facing issue in connecting to database using hibernate as we are getting "No matching authentication protocol" error.

I tried in all forums everyone suggested to upgrade ojdbc14 jar to ojdbc6 jar.

But we are not using ojdbc14 jar in my project.

We are using mostly com.springsource jars.

Answer (score 1):

I think you saw that workaround which says that SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION should be set to 8 which means allowing legacy clients to connect. I don't think that this is good idea. You should update your drivers you can get it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html).

To find jar library try to search for class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`in your IDE.

Only if you aren't able to upgrade your solution to java 7 or 8 try to do that workaround.

Workaround - to create a sqlnet.ora in the /network/admin location with the following parameter:

`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8`

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2016)

Let’s clarify a little bit **Spring** is light weight alternative to **J2EE**. Spring aim is to help structure whole application in the better way make it more consistent by pulling together best-of-breed single–tier frameworks to create a coherent architecture.

You plugged to your app **Hibernate** this is **ORM** (**O**bject-**R**elational **M**apping) framework for mapping an object-orientated domain model to a relational database.

**Hibernate** initializes **JDBC** (**J**ava **D**ata**B**ase **C**onnectivity this is API for java which defines how a client may access database) connection which could be configured:

1. **Standalone configuration** you will use driver configured inside your
   app.
2. **Datasource connection** over **JNDI** then all db drivers and
   configurations  are on app server side Hibernate user JNDI name to
   connect.

Please can you share what kind of configuration you use if you not sure please add you Hibernate configuration?

Comment: Our application currently uses Java 8 and my application is not using OracleDriver directly, because my application is using Hibernate. I am unable to find the exact hibernate jar file to upgrade.

Comment: Even if you use hibernate you need jdbc driver. Chek your dependcies. What build tool do you use mave or gradle?

Comment: We are using Jar files. We are not sure what version of Hibernate willl support Oracle 12c. Currently our hibernate version is 3.3.0.SP1

Comment: We are mostly using com.springsource...... type of jar files, but i am unable to get the latest jars from Maven. when i try to download the latest jar it is showing error. For example com.springsource.org.hibernate.jar

Answer (score 0):

### For maven users

If your project using maven, then you need to change in `pom.xml`

Use the `ojdbc6.jar/ojdbc7.jar` instead of `ojdbc14.jar`

**Use one of the following jars in your pom.xml as dependency.**

```
<!-- ojdbc6.jar example -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

OR,

```
<!-- ojdbc7.jar example -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Remove the following dependency from your pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### For gradle users

Use the dependency in your build.gradle

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6
compile group: 'oracle', name: 'ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.3'
```

or

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.easyproject/ojdbc7
compile group: 'cn.easyproject', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.0.2.0'
```

**Remove the dependency from your build.gradle**

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14
compile group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc14', version: '10.2.0.2.0'
```

### Resource Link:

https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for

Add the following in `oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora` file :

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
```

### Why you will use 8?

> **Bug 14575666**
>
> In 12.1, the default value for the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION
>   parameter has been updated to 11. This means that database clients
>   using pre-11g JDBC thin drivers cannot authenticate to 12.1 database
>   servers unless theSQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter is set to the
>   old default of 8.
>
> This will cause a 10.2.0.5 Oracle RAC database creation using DBCA to
>   fail with the ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol error in
>   12.1 Oracle ASM and Oracle Grid Infrastructure environments.
>
> Workaround: Set `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8` in the
>   oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file.

### Resource Link:

1. [ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26629916/2293534

**If 8 does not work then,**

> Prior to version 12c the default setting for
>   SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION (the equivalent parameter prior to 12c)
>   was 8  .
>
> In 12c the default is now 11.

### Resource Link:

http://www.redstk.com/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-after-upgrade-to-12c/