# spark importing data from oracle - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: python, oracle, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

While trying to read data from oracle database using spark on AWS EMR,
I am getting this error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.

Can someone let me know if anyone faced this issue and how they resolved it?

```
pyspark --driver-class-path /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar --jars   /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar

from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext, SparkConf

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@//10.200.100.142:1521/BMD", driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", 
dbtable="S_0COORDER_TEXT_D").load()
```

Answer (score 2):

Although You haven't mentioned which version of spark you are using... you can try below....

import jars to both driver & executor. So, you need to edit `conf/spark-defaults.conf` adding both lines below.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar
```

or
 you can try to pass while submitting job like below example :

```
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar
```

Comment: we are using spark 2.0.0 version. I have added jars to both driver and executor in conf/spark-defaults.conf, but I am still facing the same issue. py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: I have tried with pyspark --jars /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar, still same issue.

Comment: the same settings which you have suggested is working for a different team but not me, it is weird.

Comment: there might be specific issue in your thing. it should work. since its working other team you mentioned please accept the solution as owner!

Answer (score 1):

add codes below to your_spark_home_path/conf/spark-defaults.conf,'/opt/modules/extraClass/' is dir where i put extra jars:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath = /opt/modules/extraClass/jodbc7.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath = /opt/modules/extraClass/jodbc7.jar
```

or you can simple add jodbc7.jar to  your_spark_home_path/jars.

Comment: @BdEngineer Thats because your executors may not have the jdbc jar present. Run your spark-submit command with `--jars /path/to/jdbc.jar` argument. This argument distributes the jar to all the executors.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem on an AWS EMR cluster (emr-5.31.0).

Setting `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in `SparkSession.builder.config()`, ***or*** `spark-defaults.conf`, ***or*** with the `spark-submit --jars` command to the location of the `jodbc6.jar` did not work.

I finally got it to work by passing the Maven coordinates to `spark.jars.packages` and then I ***also*** had to set `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` to `$HOME/.ivy2/jars/*`.

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_packages_list = [
    'io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1',
    'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4',
]
spark_packages = ",".join(spark_packages_list)

home = os.getenv("HOME")

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .config("spark.jars.packages", spark_packages)
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', f"{home}/.ivy2/jars/*")
    .config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', f"{home}/.ivy2/jars/*")
)
```

Then the following worked (change parameters accordingly):

```
host = "111.111.111.111"
port = "1234"
schema = "YourSchema"
URL = f"jdbc:oracle:thin:@{host}:{port}/{schema}"

with open(f"{home}/username.file", "r") as f:
    username = f.read()

with open(f"{home}/password.file", "r") as f:
    password = f.read()

query  = "SELECT * FROM YourTable"

df = (spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", URL)
    .option("query", query)
    .option("user", username)
    .option("password", password)
    .load()
)

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

***OR***

```
properties = {
    "user": username,
    "password": password,
}

df = spark.read.jdbc(
    url=URL, 
    table="YourTable",
    properties=properties,
    )

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

for solving this problem just add suitable ojdbc.jar driver to :

```
$SPARK_HOME/jars/
```

then if the exception changed to somthing like this:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.load. : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

it is because of the conflict in ojdbc driver mentioned here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception
```

then simply change the driver