# Class.forName in Apache Spark 1.6.1 map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, classnotfoundexception

I have spark scala 1.6.1_2.10  project with 2 modules not dependent at compile time. The first modules is initiating a spark driver app.
In first module, in one of the rdd.map{} operation I am trying to load a class using reflection class.forName("second.module.function.MapOperation")

my spark-submit has both the jars for both module one as primary and other in --jars option.

This code run fine in local on my intellij.
This fails due to ClassNotFound second.module.function.MapOperation on cluster
Also fails in functional test cases with ClassNotFound, if I test the same class.

I there an issue with classloaders and using Class.forName in a spark job/operation?

Comment: possible reason is jar is missing in cluster . ... have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43720970/647053)

Comment: Nope rest of classes which are directly called (without reflection) are invoked without any issue..

Comment: can you check like this inside map method `val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.foreach(println)
` it will tell whether your jar is present or not

Comment: how are you launching the job/and which mode yarn cluster or yarn client...  can you print your spark-submit here

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the jars in hdfs and provide that path to spark submit.

This way all of the spark processes will have access to the class.