# Unable to access oracle DB in java

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to connect to a database using the below URL. It gives me an exception.

```
connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HostName:1521:ORCL";
```

But I am able to access the database using Oracle client.

Exception it gives: `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol`

Comment: That usually happens when you use an outdated JDBC driver against a current Oracle version. And the URL should be: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/orcl` the old SID based URL format (that you are using) should not be used any longer

Comment: how can i know which driver version i need to use thanks for help

Comment: `java -jar ojdbcXXXXX.jar` should display the version.

Comment: it gives me Oracle 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: then which driver version i required

Comment: That should work with any modern Oracle version. What is your Oracle server version? (Use `select * from v$version;` to get that)

Comment: oracle version is 12.1.0

Comment: Then try the modern URL syntax that I suggested

Comment: it gives same error msg

Comment: maybe one of the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100117/85421 helps. Are you sure above JAR is the one being used?

Comment: in order to connect to 12c database you need at least JDBC driver version 11.2.0.4.