# How to connect to Oracle 18c database from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, ojdbc, oracle18c

I'm coding with JavaEE and trying to access Oracle 18c database from "eclipse 2018-09" I used ojdbc8 and the ping succeeded, but I have this error : "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol".
 After some research i found out that I should set the values of the "SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11" and "SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=11" in sqlnet.ora file I didn't found them in this file so I added them but it still doesn't work.
Anyone can help me ?

```
package controleur;


/* connexion à la base de données*/

import java.sql.Connection;



import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.TimeZone;


import java.sql.*;

public class AccessDB {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
//Load the Oracle JDBC driver      
     Connection conn = null;
   try {
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") ;
     System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.");
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
   }

//The connection
   try {
       String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
       url, "system", "liza");
     System.out.println("Connected with @localhost:1521:XE.");




   } catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
   }   
 }
}
```

Comment: duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception