# Android - Oracle 12c Database Connection Issue : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: android, oracle, oracle12c, sqlexception, nosuchmethoderror

Since last 3 days I am getting problem with just simple connection of **Android - Oracle 12c Database.**

Recently I have uploaded **[Android-Oracle-Connection](https://github.com/pratikbutani/Android-Oracle-Connection)** but its for 11g version. I have used **ojdbc14.jar**

I have used following lines of code in that demo:

```
/**
 * Driver for Oracle
 */
private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";


/**
 * URL to connect database
 */
private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.102:1521:oracle"; // Change IP_Address:Database

/**
 * Creating Connection
 *
 * @param driver   driver object
 * @param url      url for db
 * @param username username
 * @param password password
 * @return Connection object
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException throwing exception
 * @throws SQLException           throwing exception
 */
public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

Now Problem is, I am using IP : **192.168.0.102** for 11g which was successfully connected but I have change IP **192.168.0.105** for 12c with same code but its not working.

I am getting error as:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

I have already [checked this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604277/1318946) and tried but getting error as:

```
W/oracle.jdbc: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:321)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:203)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:199)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
```

I have already [tried this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981073/1318946) too but getting error as:

```
2019-11-23 16:36:12.564 28567-28567/com.demo.oracle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.oracle, PID: 28567
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:230)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
```

I didn't found any tutorial or documentation to connect with 12c. Can anyone help?

Comment: Update your jdbc driver and try again. The "14" means JAVA 1.4 ojdbc14.jar.  Going to wager you are not using java 1.4.

Comment: Java 1.4 is older version I think, I am using Java 1.8. I just wanted to know that What should I do to work with Oracle 12c.

Comment: @PratikButani `ojdbc7.jar` should work for you, available here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-upc-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Old post but just to answer it, you have to add a parameter on the Database Server sqlnet.ora file to allow connection from older clients. This error happens when your client is old and server is only allows connection from recent version of sqlnet client. Example 11g client trying to connect to 18c DB Server.