# Configuring Web Config For Oracle Managed Data Access

Tags: entity-framework, oracle-manageddataaccess

After extensive Googling I can't seem to find a solution to this issue. In a nutshell I'm using Oracle Managed Data Access client with EF 6 in a MVC/Web API application.

When I run locally I can make successful calls to various operations in the Web API 2 controllers. No problems.

When I publish to our staging server, I immediately get this error:

"Message:The underlying provider failed on Open.-Inner:Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied\r\n   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager

Obviously the username/password are fine when I run locally so I feel that I'm missing putting them into a location in my web.config.

Here is my web config, you can see I'm using the entire TNS string for the Datasource value in the connection string. When I don't do that, the staging site shows an error of - TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <section name="entityFramework"  type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EISContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EISModel.csdl|res://*/EISModel.ssdl|res://*/EISModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 123.west.dc) (PORT = 1540)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = tst)));PASSWORD=password;USER ID=username&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess" />
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
    <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
  </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
   <version number="*">
   <dataSources>
    <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 123.west.dc) (PORT = 1540)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = tst)))" />
  </dataSources>
  <settings>
    <setting name="DbNotificationPort" value="-1" />
    <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="(TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)" />
    <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2\network\admin"/>
    <setting name="FetchSize" value="1048576" />
    </settings>
    </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
     <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
   </system.codedom>
   <entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to set the FIPSSecurityPolicy in the reg equal to 0 instead of the default value of 1.

Thanks to this thread: [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410951/oracle-manageddataaccess-and-ora-01017-invalid-username-password-logon-denied)