# ORA-01017: invalid username/password - On deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have a MVC5 site that I created, and it runs fine on my development server. 

However today I went to deploy to our test server and I am now locking the account.  
When I check the log files I see the error ORA-01017: invalid username/password

What I don't understand is why I am getting that.  I am using the exact same credentials to access the db.

EDIT:

We are running against an Oracle 11g DB.
No web.config changes occur during deployment.

Comment: Can you login in to oracle outside from a third party app such as pl/sql developer using the same username and password?

Comment: Yes.  I used TOAD (on my dev machine).  I also ran the MVC site (on my DEV machine) and both connect.

Comment: Are the login details the same for both dev and test servers. And are you sure it's suing the ones your supplying and not some stores ones. I had that problem recently where while developing it cached the login details and connected state. When I deployed it tried to connect twice once for the cached and once when I asked it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link resolved my issue.

I had to end up making the registry key change.  Once that was done I was able to access the DB.

[Stack Overflow Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410951/oracle-manageddataaccess-and-ora-01017-invalid-username-password-logon-denied)