# EZ connection with SID

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, odp.net

first, i saw a lot of open questions similar to my case but non shows actual solution.

lately i started to work with oracle DB v.11.2.0.3.0. 
i have DB with SID and no service name. 
i tried to connect this DB via visual studio ODP.NET (ez-connect) but there is no input field for SID.

got the following error :

```
ORA-01017:invalid username/password;logon denied.
```

however, i succeed to connect a different DB with service name and no SID. 
also, succeed to connect to this DB via sql developer tool so all details like username, password, port and connection name are correct.

how can i connect to oracle DB with SID using visual studio ODP.NET?

thank's in advanced.

Comment: Computers are too stupid to lie. If the error message is "invalid username/password", this means Oracle is complaining about the username and password; it is NOT complaining about the SID. The error message you got is actually a good sign; you can **only** get that message if the connection to the DB succeeded, and **then** it processed your username/password and found them to be invalid.

Comment: i wrote that i succeed to connect this DB via sql developer tool so all details like username, password, port and connection name are correct.

i dont see any difference between connecting via sql developer tool or visual studio...

Comment: Could be an issue with FIPS compliance. Please visit these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410951/oracle-manageddataaccess-and-ora-01017-invalid-username-password-logon-denied and also https://community.oracle.com/thread/2557592?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the FIPS security policy, by setting this key:
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy]     "Enabled"=dword:00000000

See the following links for more information and discussion on FIPS compliance and ODP.NET:

[Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410951/oracle-manageddataaccess-and-ora-01017-invalid-username-password-logon-denied)

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2557592?start=0&tstart=0