# in sysdba, i don't know user's password

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
> sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> alter session set container=pdborcl;
SQL> select username, password from dba_users
 where username like '%JAVA%';

USERNAME
------------------------------------------------------------

PASSWORD
------------------------------------------------------------

JAVA


C##JAVA



SQL>
```

when i created the IDs, i set up passwords in JAVA.

i couldn't log in SQL DEVELOPER and i got a error message, ORA-01017.

i tried to enter the password of lowercase and uppercase.

i tried to change the passwords.

```
SQL> alter user java identified by java;
succeed
SQL> alter user java identified by java11;
succeed
```

but...... because of same problem, i couldn't log in.
how can i do to solve this trouble?

my oracle is 11g.

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie

Comment: Does the user have all required permissions? (at least create session)