# Difference between ojdbc jar file versions

Tags: oracle, database-connection, ojdbc

I tried to use `ojdbc14.jar` to connect to database. I got following error message:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

After that I downgraded it to `ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar` and this error message disappeared without modification of login credentials.

There is a big difference how these behaves and error message is strange.

Comment: May be this is somewhat related to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie

Comment: @SirTesla : I can't found an answe on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@plaidshirt : that post answers some part of your question, that is the older versions of oracle doesn't maintain case sensitivity, as you were trying to connect to the oracle db client, right ??
like if your password in 9i was : myPass123, then 9i sees it as MYPASS123
whereas 11g would take it according to the case of the characters.
So, if there was some issue in the case of your password which returned **ORA-01017** gets resolved in lower versions of it, only if it was a character case issue.

Comment: I didn't change anything else than the ojdbc jar file, so database is the same.