# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when running application. Works fine if 'Run as Admin' is used

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting a `'ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password'` error when opening our vb6 application. If I keep trying this, I will eventually get a different Oracle error message saying `'account is locked out'.`

However, if I run my application with **'Run as Admin'**, it opens the app fine!

Using Oracle 11g. The Oracle database and username/schema all appears fine. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you running a Oracle 10g client (A Oracle10g - Driver) but using Oracle 11g as the database?

Comment: The client is running Oracle 11g client, as far as I am aware, but can double check.

Comment: Please do that, because when you use a Oracle10g Driver, it will work with Oracle11g, but the Oracle10g Driver will send Username and Password in UPPER CASE, but Oracle11g is casesensitive!

Comment: Create a user with uppercase username and uppercase password and try to login.

Comment: Not flagging as such (yet) but possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie/14477188

Comment: @BobJarvis, this problem seems to be the opposite. You get connected to database although you entered the wrong password!

Comment: what is the VB connection string you're using?

Comment: @watchme, yes password became case-sensitive in Oracle 11.1 (unless you disable it with `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE`). However, it applies only for new accounts or when you change your password. For existing accounts the password remains **not** case-sensitive until you modify it.

Comment: No update yet about their client and server versions. They re-imaged their machine and now they receive this error even when they 'Run As Admin'. Very strange. Still looking into it my side so will see how things go...

Comment: Client and Server are on 11.2. Issue still occurs when do not Run As Admin. No joy so far.

Comment: Also, I tried playing around with resetting password, changing case sensitivity and expiring account, but none of these scenarios caused the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to recreate this.

Happens when a user is prevented access to the registry settings on the PC.

When opening the application, you receive the Invalid Username Password message, as nothing is in the registry (or else a default password was set by the application, which didn't match their password).