# ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Tags: oracle, createuser, oracle18c, pluggable-database

Hi I've tried to create a new user in Oracle 18c XE, but I get

`ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name` error when writing

`create user student identified by "student";`

I've tried to change the container to PDB by

`SQL> alter session set container =PDB;`

as I've understood that you should set that when trying to create a local user but I get the following error:

`ORA-65011: Pluggable database PDB does not exist.`

Do you have any idea how could I create a new user with all privileges from the command prompt?

Comment: Default identifier is `XEPDB1`. Replace `PDB` with `XEPDB1`.

Comment: @Abra It worked, I managed to create the user and grant all privileges, but when I try to connect using that username and password, I get the following error: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: Connection string is `username/password@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1`

Answer (score 10):

> A user cannot be created on a **container** for a DB with vers. 12c+.

So, need to alter as you did, but should display which **pluggable databases** are available :

```
SQL> select name, pdb from v$services order by pdb, name;

NAME                                                          PDB
-----------------------------------------------           ----------
SYS$BACKGROUND                                            CDB$ROOT
SYS$USERS                                                 CDB$ROOT
pdb1                                                      PDB1
pdb2                                                      PDB2
```

and check out the container by

```
SQL>show con_name

CON_NAME
——————————
CDB$ROOT
```

and check for the pluggable databases

```
SQL> select name,open_mode  from v$pdbs;

NAME                      OPEN_MODE
-------------------       ----------
PDB$SEED                  READ ONLY
PDB1                      MOUNTED
PDB2                      MOUNTED
```

change container to a pluggable database

```
SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;
Session altered.
```

and open it

```
SQL> alter pluggable database pdb1 open;
```

Now, you can apply

```
SQL> create user student identified by student;
```

as an example.

Comment: I created a new user and granted all privileges, but when I try to connect with it I get ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie) could reply your new issue @CristinaMoroti . Seems you'd be better considering a password without quotes.

Answer (score 3):

First run the following command:

```
SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

After that, create the user:

```
SQL> create user student identified by student;
```

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to run this command. Setting this undocumented parameter might "work", but it will create the user incorrectly and in the wrong database. If you want to create a regular Oracle user, you must connect to the correct pluggable database first.