# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied with container DOCKER

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle12c

good morning I am writing because I am trying to connect to an oracle 12c database that is in an oracle container, the question is what I am doing with a user that created but I get the error ORA-01017:

[image]

On the other hand, if I try the system user with his password that can be obtained at the following link: https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition?tab=reviews, everything works fine and the connection it's correct:

[image]

As you can see below the user is already created and I can even connect from the server to the database:

[image]

Try applying what you say in this question: [ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when connecting to 11g database from 9i client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie) but no change my problem

**Update**: for some reason the changes I am making through the console I am not seeing with the SQL Developer client, I do not understand why this happens, attached evidence, where you can see that the user cesar created through the console is not visible on the server

[image]

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, maybe your login and password are incorrect, or you're attempting to connect to the wrong database or a nonexistent one.  You need to re-check everything.

Comment: For some reason the changes I am making in the server database I can not see through the sql developer client, I do not understand why, go to the sql developer with the system, check the tables and there are no users that create through command