# oracle database 19c ora-01017 invalid username/password

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, oracle19c

I create user with

```
CREATE USER "C##XXXXX" IDENTIFIED BY "PasWordorSomthingLikeThat"  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "XXX_TABLE_SPACE"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "XXX_TABLE_SPACE_TEMP";
```

but from oracleSqlDeveloper I can't login into my user And find [ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when connecting to 11g database from 9i client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie) but he said to change security!
is that oracle set this option for the access database useless? what can i do to login my oracle database without change security parameters?

error:

```
ora-01017 invalid username/password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter mentioned in your link is not valid for 19c. Try *not* using quotation marks in your create user command:

```
CREATE USER C##XXXXX IDENTIFIED BY PasWordorSomthingLikeThat  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE XXX_TABLE_SPACE
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE XXX_TABLE_SPACE_TEMP;
```

And double-check your connect string to make sure you're connecting to the right CDB or PDB for the account.

Comment: I LOVE YOU MAN :))