# Errors ORA-28040 & ORA-01017 connecting old client to Oracle DB 21c

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, oracle21c

I am trying to connect a JBOSS/Tomcat/J2EE(Jakarta EE) client to my locally installed 21c Oracle Database. The client was able to connect to a database on a coworkers computer which I believe is running an older Oracle Database version. The client originally used ojdbc14.jar, but had ojdbc7.jar.bak in the ./WEB-INF/lib/ folder as well.

So far I have tried adding the following to the sqlnet.ora file in various combinations.

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8 (also 10, 11, 12, and 12a)
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8 (also 10, 11, 12, and 12a)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (none)
```

The only thing that makes a difference is setting `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8` changes the error from `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol` `to ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`. I also tried `SET USER uname IDENTIFIED BY "pwd";` to see if that would re-hash the password to older versions as the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER` version changed.

From there I have tried the following versions of ojdbc.jar not seeing anything change.

ojdbc14.jar, ojdbc7.jar, ojdbc8.jar, ojdbc11.jar

When getting ORA-01017 I tried `ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;` according to the following post but get an `ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM` error.

[ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when connecting to 11g database from 9i client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie)

According to the Oracle DB 21 documents, that statement has been desupported.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spuss/understanding-password-case-sensitivity-and-upgrades.html#GUID-6428A98A-6621-4E49-89E5-FAFD51F04B60

I am new to Oracle DB, Tomcat, JBOSS, and J2EE and am trying to learn as fast as I can. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the two pertinent questions are:

1. Am I missing something to allow this client to talk with the 21c database?
2. For future compatibility, is there something simple to get the client to use Exclusive Mode authentication protocols?